# Best estimate for Stochastic difference equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, differential-equations, stochastic-approximation

On the subject of **Stochastic differential equations**. If we consider the **difference equation** $$\Delta x(t_n) = x(t_n) \Delta t + f(t_n) \Delta t$$ where we consider $f(t_n) \Delta t$, the driving term as a **Wiener process** (random process). Given the value of $x$ at time $t_n$, the value at time $t_{n+1}$ is then $$x(t_n + \Delta t) = x(t_n) + \Delta x(t_n) \\= x(t_n) + x(t_n) \Delta t + f(t_n) \Delta t$$ In a text it states that "upon obtaining $\Delta x (t_n)$, the best esitmate of $x$ is $\frac{\Delta x(t_n)}{\Delta t}$". Can anyone see what is meant by this?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see your question as more largely based in the probability / statistics aspect (*stochastic* DE), or in the math? I'm wondering if this would be a better fit on the [mathematics.SE] SE site.

Answer (score 1):

You have $x(t_n)+\Delta x(t_n)=x(t_n)+x(t_n)\Delta t+f(t_n)\Delta t$, so that:

$$\frac{\Delta x(t_n)}{\Delta t}=x(t_n)+f(t_n).$$

Usually Weiner processes are defined to have mean 0, so that the left hand side is indeed the best estimate of $x(t_n)$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so you are interpretting 'best estimate' to mean the quantity which has the same mean as the value $x(t_n)$?